# Process of device driver detection in linux

Tags: linux, unix, driver, device

Wanted to know how a device is detected in Linux? What exactly is the workflow of the device driver in device detection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the Kernel's job to detect devices as it has the lowest level access to the available hardware.  When the Kernel scans through all available addresses it maintains a list of Vendor and Device IDs.

To use PCI bus devices as an example, there is a Vendor ID and a Device ID associated with all PCI devices.

Device drivers are written in such a way as to identify to the Kernel what kinds of devices the driver is able to control.  Drivers may advertise that they can handle more than one vendor and device type combination.

The Kernel will allocate a driver to each device based on these IDs.  A similar process is in place for USB devices.  Older technologies like legacy devices (serial ports, parallel, ps2 mice/keyboards) will have explicitly hardcoded methods of associating particular drivers with devices.

You can use the Linux commands **lsusb** and **lspci** to see the available devices and IDs on your system.

So in direct answer to your question - the device driver usually does nothing to detect the device, at least in the first instance.  Once the driver is associated with a device (by the Kernel) the driver will likely do further interrogation of the device to ensure it contains the right firmware or is the right hardware revision, etc.

Comment: This is at least how I understand it.  I did a bit of PCI driver writing a few years back, and understanding the initial way to allocate your driver with a device is the first thing one needs to get to grips with.